# get multiple inputs instead of one

Tags: pascal

So, I'm new here and I'm new to programming generally. I made this program that I needed for a project (a pascal program using Lazarus) that allows me to get a kind of list generated by replacing * by numbers. What I need is to be able to give it multiple codes to process at once (maximum 10) instead of entering every code at once.

```
program b;

{$mode objfpc}
{$H+}

uses sysutils;

var
  sourcestr: string;
  resultstr: string;
  n: integer;

begin
  writeln('provide a string:');
  readln(sourcestr);
  for n := 0 to 99 do begin
    resultstr := StringReplace(sourcestr, '*', IntToStr(n div 10), []);
    resultstr := StringReplace(resultstr, '*', IntToStr(n mod 10), []);
    resultStr := resultStr + ':password';
    writeln(resultstr);
  end;
end.
```

I hope you could help me with this and thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Is this homework/coursework?  I'm asking because  SO isn't a homework-doing service.  Also, you need to explain more clearly exactly what you mean by "codes" and hemce "multiple codes".  As written, your code will replace at most two asterisks in `sourcestr`.  Are you wanting to replace each asterisk in sourcestr by the two substitute characters, regardless of how many asterisks there are (so that you could process, say `a**b**c**d`), or something else and if so what?

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows how to replace an arbitrary number of pairs of asterisks by the two substitute characters you are generating.

```
  for n := 0 to 9 do begin
    resultstr := sourcestr;
    while Pos('*', resultstr) > 0 do begin
      stringReplace(resultstr, '*', IntToStr(n div 10), []);
      resultstr := StringReplace(resultstr, '*', IntToStr(n mod 10), []);
    end;
    resultStr := resultStr + ':password';
    writeln(resultstr);
  end;
```

It uses the `Pos` function in a `while` loop to replace the asterisk pairs.  Be aware that the output may not be exactly what you need, because in each generated `resultstr` you will get the same substitute characters replacing each pair of asterisks, i.e.
with an input of

> a ** b ** c

the `resultstr`s generated will be like

> a00b00c
>   a11b11c

which may not be what you need.  If not, changing the code to do what you *do* need is left as an exercise for the reader, as they say.

Btw, it occurred to me later that maybe you are asking how to input and process several lines'-worth of user input.  One way to do that would be to read the lines into a TStringList (see online help) and then process that.  Something like:

```
var
  TL : TStringList;
  sourcestr : String;

begin

  TL := TStringList.Create;
  repeat
    readln(sourcestr);
    if sourcestr <> '' then
      TL.Add(sourcestr);
  until sourcestr = '';

  for i := 0 to TL.Count - 1 do begin
    sourcestr := TL[i];
    // process sourcestr however you want
  end;

  TL.Free;
```

though you could, of course, simply process sourcestr as you go along, in the repeat..until loop.